# Should i index a column or split it into separate views SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing

I have a table `Employees` which contains around 11000 rows of data. One of the columns is `Location`, within this column there are different types of location e.g. United States, France, Great Britain. I have created a clustered index on the location column. I have also created a view of this table.

I am going to create an MVC project which uses this view. What I would like to know is should I create different views with each one separated by the location or is the clustered index enough to improve performance? Or should I do both?

In my head smaller views would improve performance as in the project it will allow to search by location, and instead of searching through a huge view you now just have to search smaller views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering or anything like that is for HUGE tables, say hundreds of millions of rows. With 11000 rows, sql server will be just fine, usually even without an index.
Now if you really worry about performance, add indexes for the columns you usually search on, like your location.

Also, it might be good practice to have another table which stores locations, then only have a foreign key to that table.

One reason for poor performance on this number of rows might be that you have very large rows, for instance large `nvarchar`s, or you have large binary data (which will not be stored in the row, so not slowing down the search) but is being fetched along with other data. For instance if you pull 100 items out of the database and each one has a 4MB image,  you're reading 400MB which takes time.

Comment: Would it be good to split the view up into views based on location? Or is indexing the location column good enough? Or should i do both? My main aim is to get the best performance i can.

Comment: Each feature has its own performance overhead. Partitioning is intended for very large data sets, so its performance overhead might be quite high. For a table in the range of a few tens of thousand rows, a good design will simply yield good performance, have small rows (normalize the table, take large data like images to other tables, ...), fetch only the information you need (for instance if you're  showing only the list of items, don't fetch large descriptions that you show only in another page) and finally create indices. Settle for good enough performance, unless you are in a competition.